# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException with Selenium Firefox Webdriver script from PHP/Apache

Tags: php, apache, firefox, selenium, webdriver

We are calling a python/selenium script which utilizes the firefox webdriver.

The script works fine when run from the command line, but when called using a system/exec call from PHP via Apache, we are seeing the following error(s) in the apache logs:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have 
exited before we could connect. 
The output was: \n(firefox-bin:16178): libgnomevfs-WARNING **: 
Unable to create ~/.gnome2 directory: Permission denied\nSegmentation fault\n'
```

The point of failure is directly after the web driver tries to spawn the virtual browser using:

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1000, 800))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Has anyone come across this before? After a lot of trying, I have been unable to find a clear-cut solution. I'm presuming it is something to do with permission differences between running via cli compared to running through apache.

---

The root cause was permissions: I found that executing the script via the command line as the apache user gave a more informative error:

```
sudo -u www-data python <script>
```

I needed to add a .gnome and .gnome_private directory to the web server root (/var/www/), then chown it to be owned by www-data.